# Messages On Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

I tried to set up my iMessage account but it still is not working. It won't let me add my phone number and I can't start conversations.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to enter a **mobile number** to function with iMessage you have to enable iMessage on an **iPhone** with **your** Apple ID signed in.

If you click on iMessage on your Mac and then click

1. (Left top) Messages
2. Preferences (Or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to enter preferences instantly)
3. Accounts
4. Verify if there is an account set, if not - add one.
5. If there is an account set now, click on the account which states "iMessages" below the name
6. Check the line **You can be reached for messages at:** and enable an emailaddress here and your phone number (After you've activated iMessages on an iPhone as stated above)
7. You can even set **Start new conversations from** to be your mobile number by default if you like.
8. Congratulations, you can now send messages via iMessage on your Macbook

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your account on your iPhone and then you can set it on your phone that you are also reachable by your phone number. You cannot set this on your MacBook.